# Download/Preview documents by Guest Community Users

Tags: community

[image]Did anyone found out a solution/workaround to this issue? I find myself in an exact same situation.

I need to expose documents to Guest Users in a custom LWC page on Community.

"ContentDistribution" not accessible to Guest Users is OK but what is the alternative? Should I advise my client to store documents else where in SalesforceOrg? If yes - Where?

Regards, Aditya

Comment: Files are accessible to guest users if the record associated with hat is accessible or the file is in asset library.

Answer (score 0):

If a record is accessible to your guest user, they can access and download related files. You can check 'Who Can Access' section and you can even generate 'public links' from there.

Comment: Thank you!!  It helped me move forward                                                               
 [1]  I created a brand new Object | Added a record | Added a file to record.                                                                                                    
 [2] Added this object to Community Guest profile.                                                                         
 [3] SOQL Query in Apex code - returns results for above record when accessed by Guest                                        
 What object(s) do I query next to get hold of file download URL?

Comment: You can query public url from ContentDistribution object.

`SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,ContentDownloadUrl,DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ContentDocumentId ...`

For object reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm

Comment: Sorry for later reply.  Initially, I did not want to create Public URLs for files. I ended up creating public URLs for all files.  I wish there was a more direct way to implement this solution.   You are right in your above comment.